# is removing user credentials from session in addition to invalidate() superfluous?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am looking at a legacy code base (at least ten years old) featuring what amounts to a JSP Model 2 architecture (basically Servlets and JSP pages).

I am noticing code like the following:

```
session.removeAttribute("loginBean");
session.invalidate();
```

Is there any benefit in removing the user credentials from the session. Shouldn't `invalidate` alone be sufficient? The [invalidate documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate--) seems pretty clear on the subject.

Comment: You are correct, it is sufficient. '... then unbinds any objects bound to it'.

Comment: @Marcus: You can look at my answer  & let me know iff there are any questions

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any benefit in removing the user credentials from the
>   session. Shouldn't invalidate alone be sufficient ?

Yes, there is a benefit and it is a best practice to remove the sensitive information like `usercredentials` object before invalidating the `HttpSession` from the security perspective as explained below:

When you call `invalidate`() on the `HttpSession` object, the J2EE container internally triggers the `HttpSessionListener sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se)` method. So, if you don't `remove` the `usercreadentials` object from the session, you can still be able to retrieve it inside `sessionDestroyed` method.

**So, the point is it is a best practice to remove the sensitive information from `HttpSession/Cache/`etc.. as soon as we know that the data is no longer required so that the `object` (like `usercredentials`) will no more be reachable, which will reduce the scope for misuse.**

You can look at **Guideline 2-2** the below quote from **Java secure coding guide**:

> Some information, such as Social Security numbers (SSNs) and
>   passwords, is highly sensitive. This information should not be kept
>   for longer than necessary nor where it may be seen, even by
>   administrators.

You can look at [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#2)

Comment: What is the problem with being able to retrieve session attributes in the `sessionDestroyed()` method?

Comment: You can look for the Java secure coding guide reference, the rule is not to keep the secure data for LONGER periods.